# Another way to count occurrence in a list

Tags: python, list, count

I have this list:

```
['Boston Americans', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Braves', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Cincinnati Reds', 'Cleveland Indians', 'New York Giants', 'New York Giants', 'New York Yankees', 'Washington Senators', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees']
```

Say I want to count how many times `"Boston Americans"` is in list.

How can I do that without using the `.count` method `list.count("Boston Americans")` or any import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count :)

```
count = 0
for item in items:
    if item == 'Boston Americans':
        count += 1
print count
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function :

```
>>> l=['Boston Americans', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Braves', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Cincinnati Reds', 'Cleveland Indians', 'New York Giants', 'New York Giants', 'New York Yankees', 'Washington Senators', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees']
>>> sum(1 for i in l if i=="Boston Americans")
1
>>> sum(1 for i in l if i=='Boston Red Sox')
4
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to use `sum`:

```
sum( x==value for x in mylist )
```

Here, we use the fact `True` and `False` can be treated as the integers 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
>>> a = ['Boston Americans', 'New York Giants', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Chicago Cubs', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Boston Braves', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Chicago White Sox', 'Boston Red Sox', 'Cincinnati Reds', 'Cleveland Indians', 'New York Giants', 'New York Giants', 'New York Yankees', 'Washington Senators', 'Pittsburgh Pirates', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'Philadelphia Athletics', 'St. Louis Cardinals', 'New York Yankees']
>>> len(filter(lambda x : x=='Boston Americans',a))
1
>>> len(filter(lambda x : x=='Boston Red Sox',a))
4
```

Others good Method but you need to import modules

using `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
>>> my_count = {x:len(list(y)) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(a))}
>>> my_count['Boston Americans']
1
>>> my_count['Boston Red Sox']
4
```

using `collection.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_count = Counter(a)
>>> my_count['Boston Americans']
1
>>> my_count['Boston Red Sox']
4
```

Comment: "How can i do that without using the count method"

Comment: yep was updating it :)

Comment: "How can i do that **without...any import**?"

Comment: @iCodez check the last one filter and lambda :)